# Does the Python "open" function save its content in memory or in a temp file?

Tags: python

For the following Python code:

```
fp = open('output.txt', 'wb')
# Very big file, writes a lot of lines, n is a very large number
for i in range(1, n):
    fp.write('something' * n)
fp.close()
```

The writing process above can last more than 30 min. Sometimes I get the error `MemoryError`. Is the content of the file before closing stored in memory or written in a temp file?  If it's in a temporary file, what is its general location on a Linux OS?

**Edit:**

Added fp.write in a for loop

Comment: Are you actually issuing multiple calls to `fp.write`, or collecting it all in one big string and writing out at once? The latter would be rather inefficient.

Comment: It's calling multiple write in a for loop.

Comment: show the code. if you write the lines one line by one line,it should not be a problem.

Comment: 'something' * n is going to be constructed on each iteration, and is going to become quite large as n increases.  Your MemoryError probably has more to do with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's stored in the operating system's disk cache in memory until it is flushed to disk, either implicitly due to timing or space issues, or explicitly via [`fp.flush()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.flush).

Comment: After the question was revised, it's now clear that `'something' * n` is going to cause serious memory problems when `n` gets large.  File writing has nothing to do with `'something' * n` exhausting memory.

Answer (score 3):

There will be write buffering in the Linux kernel, but at (ir)regular intervals they will be flushed to disk. Running out of such buffer space should never cause an application-level memory error; the buffers should empty before that happens, pausing the application while doing so.

Answer (score 3):

Building on ataylor's comment to the question:

You might want to nest your loop. Something like

```
for i in range(1,n):
    for each in range n:
        fp.write('something')
fp.close()
```

That way, the only thing that gets put into memory is the string `"something"`, not `"something" * n`.

Comment: +1: Creating `"something" * n` for large values of `n` will exhaust memory.  Writing to a file uses very little memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you a writing out a large file for which the writes might fail you a better off flushing the file to disk yourself at regular intervals using `fp.flush()`. This way the file will be in a location of your choosing that you can easily get to rather than being at the mercy of the OS:

```
fp = open('output.txt', 'wb')
counter = 0
for line in many_lines:
    file.write(line)
    counter += 1
    if counter > 999:
        fp.flush()
fp.close()
```

This will flush the file to disk every 1000 lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you write line by line, it should not be a problem. You should show the code of what you are doing before the write. For a start you can try to delete objects where not necessary, use `fp.flush()` etc..

Answer (score 0):

File writing should never give a memory error; with all probability, you have some bug in another place.

If you have a loop, and a memory error, then I would look if you are "leaking" references to objects.
Something like:

```
def do_something(a, b = []):
    b.append(a)
    return b

fp = open('output.txt', 'wb') 

for i in range(1, n): 
    something = do_something(i)
    fp.write(something)

fp.close()
```

I am now picking just an example, but in your actual case the reference leak may be much more difficult to find; however this case will just leak memory inside `do_something` because of the way Python handles default parameters of functions.