# Running out of RAM when writing to a file line by line [Python]

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, file-io, amazon-ec2, spacy

I have a data processing task on some large data. I run the script on EC2 using Python that looks something like the following:

```
with open(LARGE_FILE, 'r') as f:
    with open(OUTPUT_FILE, 'w') as out:
        for line in f:
            results = some_computation(line)
            out.write(json.dumps(results))
            out.write('\n')
```

I loop over the data line by line and write the results to another file line by line.

After running it for a few hours, I can't log in to the server. I would have to restart the instance to continue.

```
$ ssh ubuntu@$IP_ADDRESS
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

It's likely the server is running out of RAM. When writing to the file, RAM slowly creeps up. I am not sure why memory would be a problem when reading and writing line by line.

I have ample hard drive space.

I think closest to this issue: [Does the Python "open" function save its content in memory or in a temp file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239888/does-the-python-open-function-save-its-content-in-memory-or-in-a-temp-file)

Comment: what happens in the `some_computation()` function?

Comment: my bet is on json.dumps. Possible duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24239613/memoryerror-using-json-dumps] (looking for ways of avoiding python json.dumps running out of memory)

Comment: so, you may try `json.dump(some_computation(line), out)` instead of `results = some_computation(line); out.write(json.dumps(results))`

Comment: .@tokestermw try adding a swap file to instance or increase swapfile size.... Does the code run locally without problems?

Comment: `json.dumps` only dumps a small dictionary per line. Each line in the file is a sentence and `some_computation` annotates the sentence and turns it into a dictionary.

Comment: actually might be related to spacy inside `some_computation`: https://github.com/spacy-io/spaCy/issues/289

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using SpaCy to do some preprocessing of text. Looks like using the tokenizer causes steady memory growth.

https://github.com/spacy-io/spaCy/issues/285