# Python MemoryError with Queue and threading

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I'm currently writing a script that reads reddit comments from a large file (5 gigs compressed, ~30 gigs of data being read). My script reads the comments, checks for some text, parses them, and sends them off to a Queue function (running in a seperate thread). No matter what I do, I always get a MemoryError on a specific iteration (number 8162735 if it matters in the slightest). And I can't seem to handle the error, Windows just keeps shutting down python when it hits. Here's my script:

```
import ujson
from tqdm import tqdm
import bz2
import json
import threading
import spacy
import Queue
import time
nlp = spacy.load('en')
def iter_comments(loc):
    with bz2.BZ2File(loc) as file_:
        for i, line in (enumerate(file_)):
            yield ujson.loads(line)['body']
objects = iter_comments('RC_2015-01.bz2')
q = Queue.Queue()
f = open("reddit_dump.bin", 'wb')
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        f.write(item)
        q.task_done()
for i in range(0, 2):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
def finish_parse(comment):
    global q
    try:
        comment_parse = nlp(unicode(comment))
        comment_bytes = comment_parse.to_bytes()
        q.put(comment_bytes)
    except MemoryError:
        print "MemoryError with comment {0}, waiting for Queue to empty".format(comment)
        time.sleep(2)
    except AssertionError:
        print "AssertionError with comment {0}, skipping".format(comment)
for comment in tqdm(objects):
    comment = str(comment.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
    if "&gt;" in comment:
        c_parse_thread = threading.Thread(target=finish_parse, args=(comment,))
        c_parse_thread.start()          
q.join()
f.close()
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Include the complete traceback you see; "I always get a MemoryError" is, believe it or not, too vague.

Comment: Also do _some_ research - we can't run your code.  For example, what happens if you stop calling `nlp()`?  It's not hard to find reports of growing memory use from `spaCy` users; e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37779050/running-out-of-ram-when-writing-to-a-file-line-by-line-python

So do whatever you can to rule out `spaCy`.  If you try _not_ using it and find memory use stops growing without bounds, then "the problem" has been identified.

Comment: spaCy is a module I use regularly, MemoryErrors in spaCy are caused by the lack of enough memory to load the parsing models. This isn't that. I've tried to do alot of research, but what else should I do?

Comment: And when I ran this I didn't get a traceback, Windows would just say that python.exe stopped working.

Comment: "python.exe stopped working" is not at all the same as "get a MemoryError".  Already gave a link to one example of a report of spaCy becoming increasingly ill-behaved _over time_, and their scenario sounds a lot like yours (invoking spaCy functions many, many times).  And already suggested you try to rule that out via experiment:  take spaCy out of it, and see whether the program runs to completion then.  It will or it won't.  Either way, you'll learn something new.

Comment: At the same time, my memoryerror exception is called. I could try that, and I will, thanks. My only point was that I've used spacy in pretty much this exact same usage scenario before. I'll try though. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool!  My only real ;-) point is that nobody can guess by staring at your code.  Instead you need to try removing things, until the problem goes away.  The "ideal" question is described here:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Try setting a limit to the queue size (e.g. `queue = Queue(1000)`) to avoid having it grow overwhelmingly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its not in your code but may be in the data. Have you tried to skip that iteration?

```
x = 0
for comment in tqdm(objects):
    x += 1
    if x != 8162735

        comment = str(comment.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
        if "&gt;" in comment:
            c_parse_thread = threading.Thread(target=finish_parse, args=(comment,))
            c_parse_thread.start()
```

Comment: That's what my `except MemoryError:` should do. At that point I wait a couple seconds for the Queue to empty a bit and skip the iteration.