# Python3 How could i make Reading and writing using With

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, file-io

Hello How i could make Python Write and Read at the sametime using (with) i did this simple function to add names in txt file but the output is usully empty...

```
def student():
    with open("students.txt","w+") as my_file:
        for i in range(20):
            user = input("Enter your name : ")
            my_file.write(f"{user}\n")
        print(my_file.read())

student()
```

tried r+ w+ a+ but none of them were working only r works but then i can't add to the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reposition the cursor to the start of the file, write moves it to the end:

```
def student():
    with open("students.txt", "w+") as my_file:
        for i in range(20):
            user = input("Enter your name : ")
            my_file.write(f"{user}\n")

        my_file.seek(0)  # reposition cursor to start of file
        print(my_file.read())

student()
```

Comment: so my_file.read() reads only below the cursor? + what if i want to read from line 10 and below do i do my_file.seek(10) ?

Comment: The seek function moves the pointer (cursor if you like that analogy) to some byte offset which may be absolute or relative depending on the second argument. seek(10) will move to an absolute offset - i.e., 10 bytes from the beginning of the file. This is because the second parameter defaults to zero which is equal to os.SEEK_SET. You cannot seek to a particular line number **unless** all lines are the same length. In such a case the offset can be calculated as a multiple of the line length

Answer (score 0):

The `with` statement is syntactic sugar that removes the need to close a file once opened. In Python, the contents of what you are trying to write to the file are not flushed onto the disk *until the file is closed* ([read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239888/does-the-python-open-function-save-its-content-in-memory-or-in-a-temp-file)). This means, that within the context manager (`with` statement), the file is still open and  the contents empty. You could open the file again after closing it (after the `with` statement) to read the contents, but it's inefficient. If all you are trying to do is print out the result, try this:

1. Generate a list of names in the for loop (don't write to the file here).
2. Write list of names in bulk to the file (using `join` to add newlines).
3. Print list of names.